# std::atomic in VS2017 with CLI flag

Tags: stl, visual-studio-2017, c++-cli, c++17, atomic

Microsoft docs site says that std::atomic is blocked for projects which are compiled with CLR flag: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/atomic 
I didn't know it and used atomic header in the not managed class in non-CLR project, but this header is included in another CLR project cpp file where not managed class instance is allocated for using in managed class. 
And it compiles well. Why? As I understand, it should not work. Or Microsoft have fixed it but haven't updated wiki?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I checked  header and there is an only one CLR-oriented restriction:

```
 #ifdef _M_CEE_PURE
 #error <atomic> is not supported when compiling with /clr:pure.
 #endif /* _M
```

It means that it actually should work with modern CLI